# Protractor and testing offline app

Tags: caching, offline, protractor

I was wondering is there anyway to do E2E testing for an offline app with protractor?
I cache my pages in the application cache and store data using localForage, testing it online is fine, but I also need to test it offline, is this even possible? If not what are the solutions?

Comment: how did you do your testing on localForage with protractor? Can you contact me please